# Elixir: rename key in dictionary

Tags: dictionary, elixir, key, rename

I have following list of maps:

```
[
  %{
    code: "test",
    expired_at: ~U[2020-10-27 17:49:47Z],
  },
  %{
    code: "test",
    expired_at: ~U[2021-07-30 13:54:11Z],
  }
]
```

What is the most sophisticated way to rename key `code` to `product_code` for all map entities in the list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably not "the most sophisticated way", but I think a nice way would be with pattern matching, using an anonymous function with a clause to match what you want to change, and one for everything else:

```rb
iex> l = [
...>   %{
...>     code: "test",
...>     expired_at: ~U[2020-10-27 17:49:47Z],
...>   },
...>   %{
...>     code: "test",
...>     expired_at: ~U[2021-07-30 13:54:11Z],
...>   }
...> ]
[
  %{code: "test", expired_at: ~U[2020-10-27 17:49:47Z]},
  %{code: "test", expired_at: ~U[2021-07-30 13:54:11Z]}
]
iex> Enum.map(l, &Map.new(&1, fn
...>   {:code, code} -> {:product_code, code}
...>   pair -> pair
...> end))
[
  %{expired_at: ~U[2020-10-27 17:49:47Z], product_code: "test"},
  %{expired_at: ~U[2021-07-30 13:54:11Z], product_code: "test"}
]
```

> Notice the use of [`Map.new/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html?#new/2) which creates a Map from the given enumerable with the elements that result from applying the given function to the enumerable

Or an alternative that might be more clear, without using `Map.new/2` like that or iterating over the maps' keys, could be using [`Map.delete/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html?#delete/2) and [`Map.put/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html?#put/3):

```rb
iex> Enum.map(l, fn %{code: code} = element ->
...>   element
...>   |> Map.delete(:code)
...>   |> Map.put(:product_code, code)
...> end)
[
  %{expired_at: ~U[2020-10-27 17:49:47Z], product_code: "test"},
  %{expired_at: ~U[2021-07-30 13:54:11Z], product_code: "test"}
]
```

Answer (score 6):

While the answer by @sbacarob is perfectly correct, it might quickly become noisy if the subject to update is deeply nested.

In such a case [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) provides a great, extremely underrated mechanism to update nested structures, called [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html?). For this particular case, we might use [`Kernel.update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#update_in/3) with [`Access.all/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#all/0) to get to all the elements of the list.

```rb
update_in(
  list,
  [Access.all()],
  &(with {v, m} <- Map.pop(&1, :code),
    do: Map.put(m, :product_code, v))
)
#⇒ [
#    %{expired_at: ~U[2020-10-27 17:49:47Z], product_code: "test"},
#    %{expired_at: ~U[2021-07-30 13:54:11Z], product_code: "test"}
#  ]
```